# Overloaded operator [] not being used

Tags: c++

Given a minimal example:

```
#ifndef ARR_H_
#define ARR_H_

#include <iostream>

class Array {
    public:
        Array();
        int operator[](int idx);
    private:
        int arr[10];
};

int Array::operator[](int idx) {
    std::cout << "ok";
    return arr[idx];
}

#endif
```

and I attempt to create an object

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Create" << std::endl;
    Array obj();
    int i = obj[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get the error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:18: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
     int i = obj[0];
                  ^
main.cpp:7:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘Array (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

Why does it not use my `operator[]`?

Comment: The most vexing parse.

Comment: A hint is in the error. `Array (*)()` is a pointer to function taking no arguments and returning an `Array`. That's not what you'd intended `obj` to be.

Comment: This is **not** the most vexing parse. It's a slighly vexing parse :)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Array obj();
```

is a function declaration that has no parameters and has return type Array.

Just write

```
Array obj;
```

Take into account that if you want to use the operator to assign values to the elements of the array then it is better when it returns reference to an element

```
int & operator[](int idx);
```

Also you could declare this operator for constant objects

```
const int & operator[](int idx) const;
```

or

```
int operator[](int idx) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is treated as a function declaration rather than object.

```
Array obj();
```

Replace with

```
Array obj;
```